# Run combined parameters in function

Tags: javascript

I would like to combine the following repetitive code, but I have absolutely no idea how. It's a simple piece of code to turn numbers into digital numbers (as you would see on a digital clock).

**Current code**

```
function twoDigits() {
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
}
```

**What I'd like to achieve** (or anything like this)

```
function twoDigits(seconds, minutes) {
    var param = this.value();
    if (this < 10) {
        param = '0' + param;
    }
}
```

Would that make sense? How should this be done anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have repetitive code, you can factor it out into a function. In your case, a function that accepts a number and turns it into a two-digit string:

```
function asTwoDigits(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : String(num);
}
```

Then

```
function twoDigits(seconds, minutes) {
    seconds = asTwoDigits(seconds);
    minutes = asTwoDigits(minutes);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What would the use of a string be when this is solely about numbers? Pardon my inexperience.

Comment: @Levano: This isn't solely about numbers. You have `'0' + seconds` in your code -- that produces a string. Numbers have no fixed number of digits, only *representations* of numbers (strings, literals) do.

Answer (score 0):

`function twoDigits(...timeUnits) {
Return timeUnits.map(unit=> unit < 10 ? ‘0’ + unit :unit`

This will return an array with the numbers.

Comment: Best not to have a chaotic result, and *always* ensure you convert the number to string, whether it needs the leading zero or not.